# Destructuring an array of objects inside an object

Tags: ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an object with the following structure:

```
const inventory = {
    item: {
        details: [
            {
                name: "Item A",
                type: "Type A"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to access the **name** property with ***pure destructuring***. So far I got to the first element in the **details array**.

```
const {item: {details: [firstDetail]}} = inventory;
```

I don't know where to go from here to access the **name** property. I was expecting it to be like the following but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

```
const {item: {details: [firstDetail]: {name}}} = inventory;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `{name}` *instead* of `firstDetail`:

```js
const inventory = {
    item: {
        details: [
            {
                name: "Item A",
                type: "Type A"
            }
        ]
    }
}

const {item: {details: [{name}]}} = inventory;

console.log(name);
```